# Why is this VBA crashing excel? (Re-open worksheet)

Tags: vba, excel

```
Public Sub Reopen()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Workbooks.Open "K:\notarealpath\Testamundo.xlsm"

End Sub
```

I need to refresh the workbook by closing and reopening it and this seems to work, as i assigned it to a button, and when clicked it asks if i am sure i want to reopen the book which is fine.

Sometimes it works ONCE, then doing it a second time completely crashes Excel and when going back to the VBA screen it complains it's out of memory after a crash.

Comment: Is the macro external to the workbook you're trying to close and re-open? Also do you close the workbook if open before you open it. I can't see you doing that in the code above. It could be crashing as you're trying to open an already open workbook

Comment: Also, define what you mean by "Refresh"? There are many options to re-calculate or re-pull data sources or other things that may be a better solution.

Comment: Is there anything being called under ThisWorbook.Open?

Comment: To echo the Scott, why would you need to re-open a workbook to refresh it? I literally can't think of a single event that the workbook_open event can access, but that VBA can't.

Comment: I have VBA in outlook pulling the body text from emails out into one of the sheet on this workbook.

I need a button to refresh the data because as emails comes in the workbook needs to be refreshed to see the new generated lines of text.

The only way i have found to do this is to have it closed and reopened because just "refreshing" the data doesn't work.

Comment: Also Tom: When running the vba once in a blue moon it actually does work, it pops up with a box saying am i sure i want to re-open this sheet and lose changes.. i press yes and it works.

But like i said it only does this about 1/10 trys, and trying it again straight after results in crashing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a close, delay, then open in the same macro?  Make sure this is saved outside of the workbook beyond worked on (possibly a quick-button referencing a macro saved in XLSTART).

```
Workbooks("Testamundo.xlsm").Close SaveChanges:=False
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")
Workbooks.Open "K:\notarealpath\Testamundo.xlsm"
```

Comment: This just closes the workbook and doesn't re-open it.
Just a blank screen after that.

Comment: @Steve101 I just tested this using a local drive and file, where the macro was saved as .xla inside of my XLSTART folder, and it was working for me.  I am using Excel 2016, though that shouldn't make a difference.  Two things to check: your system clock is correctly updating (time as Now is from the system clock) , and that the path you are using is correct.

Comment: It on a cloud session so i know everything is up to date and correct, and the folder path is definalty correct because like i said sometimes it does in fact work, but only ever once.
Also i am on 2013.

Comment: My only initial guess is that 5 seconds might not be enough time to delay before executing the open?  I'm a bit at a loss for how to help with possible networking issues, as this approach works locally.  Sorry I couldn't be more help, @Steve101